# How To Expand WebView To Full Screen On Action

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview, gesture

So, I have an app that I'm writing, and it is essentially a web view connected to multiple buttons, and when a button is pressed, the link opens. However, what I need is method of expanding the web view to full screen when it receives a gesture of two fingers expanding, and also for it going back to normal when it receives the action of pinching.

Much appreciated, and as a starting coder, I don't know how to do it myself, so your help is much needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use UIGestureRecognizer here. Something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

…

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    webView.frame = (gestureRecognizer.scale > 1) ? self.view.bounds : initialFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And then if you want your web view to be really fullscreen, make your navigation bar and status bar transparent when scale is > 1.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I will try and see what I can do with this.

Comment: Two errors, and since I'm slightly new to gestures, I am not sure how to fix it. The problems are that "scale" is not of type webView, and that initialFrame is undefined. What do I need to  do to fix the first, and what do I define initialFrame as?

Comment: Scale (CGFloat) is a property of UIPinchGestureRecognizer, which tells you if the user is moving two fingers toward each other (zoom in) or from each other (zoom out). and initial frame is a CGRect, actually the initial frame of your webView, you need to define it.

Comment: So, I need to attach scale to the PinchGestureRecognizer, and also, then, how am I to define the CGRect? I've never done any interface coding before, so that's what I need to learn.

Comment: CGRect initialFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f);